# React Native - call method when exit app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to call a method to change a value from `AsyncStorage`. So I tried using `AppState` to check app is closed.

```
componentWillMount(){
    AppState.addEventListener('change', state => {
    if (state === 'active') {
      console.log("THIS IS ACTIVE");
    } else if (state === 'background') {
      console.log("THIS IS BG");
    } else if (state === 'inactive') {
      console.log("THIS IS INAVTIVE");
    }
  });
}
```

However, it not calling to the `inactive`, am I doing right ? or there is another better way to check the app is closed. Thank a lot

Comment: It only works on iOS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the app was closed, I think you could use `componentWillUnmount` of the component.
According to [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/appstate.html#appstate):

> **inactive** - This is a state that occurs when transitioning between
>   foreground & background, and during periods of inactivity such as
>   entering the Multitasking view or in the event of an incoming call

So to do something before the app is closed, put it inside the `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: tried `componentWillUnmount` not calling also, any idea ?